# grep: memory exhausted on big file when using pipe

Tags: grep

When I try to find a specific byte with `grep` not using pipe I get some output:

```
$ grep -aboP "\\x55" bigfile
510:U
1049086:U
1049598:U
```

But when a pattern is supplied via pipe then there is a memory exhausted error:

```
$ echo "\\\\x55" | grep -aboPf - bigfile
grep: memory exhausted
```

Why does it happen and how to make it work?

Comment: Note that `"\\x55"` is `'\x55'` while if your shell is bash in its default configuration, `echo "\\\\x55"` outputs `\\x55`. Some other `echo` implementations would output `\x55`. It's not a good idea to use echo or double quotes when backslashes are involved.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The same happens when single quotes are used.

Comment: Do you mean that `grep -aboP '\x55' bigfile` is OK, but `printf '%s\n' '\x55' | grep -aboPf - bigfile` returns with `memory exhausted`?

Comment: This `echo '\\\\x55' | grep -aboPf - bigfile` causes memory exhausted problem but for some reason this `echo '\x55' | grep -aboPf - bigfile` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

All right, using single quotes and removing some backslashes seems to work:

```
$ echo '\x55' | grep -aboPf - bigfile
510:U
1049086:U
1049598:U
```

Thanks @StéphaneChazelas for the hint.